# Parse Errors in Objective-C Code

Tags: objective-c

I am getting 2 errors on line 10:

> Expected a type

and

> Expected ; after method prototype

upon compiling my app.

The file called `NSBundle+NYTPhotoViewer.m` which shows error has the following code -

#### CODE

```
#import "NSBundle+NYTPhotoViewer.h"
#import "NYTPhotosViewController.h"      // This is line 10

@implementation NSBundle (NYTPhotoViewer)

+ (instancetype)nyt_photoViewerResourceBundle {
    static NSBundle *resourceBundle = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        NSString *resourceBundlePath = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[NYTPhotosViewController class]] pathForResource:@"NYTPhotoViewer" ofType:@"bundle"];
        resourceBundle = [self bundleWithPath:resourceBundlePath];
    });
    return resourceBundle;
}

@end
```

Comment: So what is inside NYTPhotosViewController.h? Most likely something wrong in that file instead of this.

Comment: Or  in "NSBundle+NYTPhotoViewer.h"

Comment: “Parse Errors in Swift Code” – There is no Swift code. That is Objective-C.